# What is the difference between:= and : in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I’ve been having a hard time trying to figure out the difference between “:=” and “=” in Solidity. I keep on thinking it is the same thing but I’m not sure about it. Can you please tell me the difference between them and what they are each used for?

Comment: There's nothing special about the `:=` operator in Solidity. It's the same as in all programming languages. See [What is the := operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405820/what-is-the-operator) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` is the assignment operator in solidity. In assembly `:=` is also the assignment operator.

You cannot interchange them, `:=` is invalid in solidity and `=` is invalid in assembly.

Comment: So what I’m getting is that you should only use := in assembly and only = when it’s not in assembly?

Comment: @ZSnyder It is a syntax error otherwise.